# nginix setup for cas and distributed application

Tags: java, tomcat, nginx, cas

I'm having a distributed application with different modules running on different tomcats ports.
For example login service (`CAS`) is running on 8080 tomcat port, Reporting service of application is running on another tomcat say 8081 port. Main application is itself running  in side different tomcat say port 8083 and I have single domain for the application i.e. [www.example.com.com](http://www.example.com).

I am really wondering how will I manage this using `nginix` and if user is getting logged in to application  and tries to access module on other sever how will session be preserved.

In short how can I configure `nginix` for a distributed application i.e. application distributed over several servers.

below is the content on nginix file.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com;
    charset utf-8;
   rewrite     ^(.*)   https://$server_name$1 permanent;
 }

server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/server.key;
    server_name mysite.com;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite-qa-error.log;
    charset utf-8;

    location ~ ^/cas/(.*)$ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:140;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
```

mysite application is running on 9001 tomcat port.

```
how will i redirect nginix to application from cas
```

Comment: can you rely on cookies/auth headers for sessions or a session store (preferably distributed in-memory and if not, then a database)?  This way, you can run modules on different ports or even servers - and you can run nginx as a proxy in front of those app servers.  Nginx would simply relay the cookie/auth headers back (provided you're not stripping them at nginx)

Comment: there are also nginx modules that integrate directly with memcached/redis that you could look into and rely on for sessions but you still need to communicate user info to tomcat

Comment: I really don't have any idea on this can you please elaborate the process that you have mentioned above and some examples on nginx configuration to handle this.I am new to nginx and really need help on this topic.If there is some other approach please let me know that also.Thanks

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you catch up on RESTful architecture first and then if needed, see if you need a distributed in-memory grid like infinispan/hazelcast or database like mongo/mysql/postgres for session storage.

Comment: I was able to access the cas login page but when i log in,browser replies the page is not  redirecting properly.
No clue how to redirect nginix to application after login to cas server.Please help me.

Comment: can you share your default file from site-available?

Comment: Hi @alihaider i have updated the nginix file content above.
nhinix redirect the user to cas login page .but after providing log -in information the web page gives error regarding infinite loop.How will the user be redirected to main application.Do need to make entries in cas application or this is to be handled by nginix.Please guide me.

Comment: Hi All so finally we were able to setup cas and its accessible now.Application is casified now. but as shown above i was redirecting nginix to tomcat port but now i want to include haproxy in between. But when i provide haproxy port in nginix everything breaks and request are not forwarded to tomcat